# How to change the Active Variant Subsystem with mask parameter

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to change the active variant subsystem changing some popup parameter in a mask. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is verified to work in 2014b.

1. (In the Function Block Parameters for your Variant Subsystem)
   First, set your Variant control to a unique variable for each variant subsystem something like ***variant1*** and ***variant2***.
2. Then check '*Override variant conditions and use the following variant*'
3. Add a Mask, then in the Mask Editor:
4. Add a 'Promote' Parameter.
5. Now set the name of this parameter to something like '*whichVariant*'
6. Under Type options for that parameter select the top level model, select 'Variant:' in the Promotable parameters, and click it over to Promoted Parameters
7. Uncheck 'Visible' for this parameter
8. Then add something like a check box parameter
9. Set the name of this parameter to something like '*doEnable*'
10. Then in the callback for this variable insert:

> ```
> doEnable = get_param(gcb,'doEnable');
> if strcmp(doEnable,'on')
>     set_param(gcb,'whichVaraint','variant1');
> else
>     set_param(gcb,'whichVariant','variant2');
> end
> ```

11. Then in the initialization tab of the Mask Editor add the exact same code

Now you should be good to go.  You can modify the code for more variants, use radio buttons instead, etc.  The basics are here though.